# EmojiPicker React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using EmojiPicker in my ReactJS application. When I click on an emoji, it doesn't appear in the input text area but instead shows up in the console. After sending the message, the text and the emoji update correctly on the UI. I'm wondering what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it. Here's a sample of my code:

```
const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");
    console.log(newComment);

const [showEmoji, setShowEmoji] = useState(false);

    const handleShowEmoji =(postId)=> {
        if(postId){
            setShowEmoji(!showEmoji)
        }
    }

    const addEmoji =(e)=> {
      const sym = e.unified.split("_")
      console.log(sym);
      const emojiArray = [];
      sym.forEach((el)=> emojiArray.push("0x" + el));
      let emoji = String.fromCodePoint(...emojiArray);
      setNewComment(newComment + emoji);
    }

# # <EmojiPicker searchDisabled width={250} height={250} onEmojiClick={addEmoji}/>
```